# Customizing UINavigationBar as in Fox news iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar

How can the UINavigationBar customizations be done? Is it using subclassing or categories?

[image: Fox news iphone app]

I am interested in 2 aspects:

1. Adding an image to the NavBar (like the FOXNEWS logo)
2. Customizing the back button to "Shows". (the back button usually takes the title of the previous view in the stack, but there is no title in previous view.)

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the Fox News app it looks like they just set the tint color of the navigation bar. As for the Fox News logo, it's probably just an image view on the title view of the navigation bar. This code goes into a view controller's `viewDidLoad` method:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:/* Custom color here */];

UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"]];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:logoView];
[logoView release];
```

To customize the back button you need to place this in the `viewDidLoad` method of the *previous* view controller (i.e. the one that this button leads back to):

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Shows"
    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];
[backButton release];
```

If you want to use a totally custom background image for your application's navigation bar, you need to create a custom `UINavigationBar` category and draw the image within its `drawRect:` method. Something like this:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarBackgroundImage)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-bar"] drawInRect:rect];

    // Optionally you can set the tintColor here to go with the background
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

adding image to navigation bar use this code

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

UIColor *color = [UIColor blackColor]; //this use to set button color in FoxNew Site //button color
UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed: @"ImageName"];
[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
self.tintColor = color;

}
```

create category for UINavigationBar

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
     }

@end
```

Comment: I tried this, but the image does not animate when the navbar is animating (when new view is pushed or popped).

Comment: @sleepy: That is due to how `UINavigationBar` works. It's perfectly normal. If you still want to get it animating, I'm not sure how.